# Why does my convex optimisation problem become infeasible when number of variables are halved?

Tags: python, mathematical-optimization, cplex, cvxpy

I have a problem which I have defined in order to specify when to run a pump to deliver water over a 24 hour period for the best cost.

The constraints which I have currently setup are:

- Reservoir level must be kept above 2.0m
- Reservoir level must be kept below 2.6m
- Total volume delivered must be >= minimum volume of 250,000 litres

The issue I have that this works perfectly in 15 minute intervals which gives 96 periods, of 2 speeds = 192 variables. However, when I try to take this down to 48 periods of 2 speeds = 96 variables I get that the solution is infeasibly for some reason.

My problem is defined as below:

```
    def optimiser(self, cost_, volume_,v_min,flow_,min_level,max_level,initial_level,period_lengths,out_flow_, errors, hours_) :
        """
        This function optimises the regime possible combinations using convex optimisation. We assign and define the problem and uses `GLPK_MI` to solve our problem.

        Parameters
        ----------
        cost_
            Numpy Array
        volume_
            Numpy Array
        v_min
            Float -> minimum volume
        flow_
            Numpy Array
        min_level
            Float -> minimum level
        max_level
            Float -> maximum level
        initial_level
            Float -> initial level
        period_lengths
            Integer -> number of period lengths
        out_flow_
            Numpy Array
        errors
            Exceptions -> error handling

        Returns
        ----------
        selection
            Solved problem with the best possible combination for pumping regime.
        """
        FACTOR =  0.001*1800*self.RESERVOIR_VOLUME
        CHANGABLE_LENGTHS = len(period_lengths)
        input_flow_matrix=np.zeros((max(period_lengths), CHANGABLE_LENGTHS))
        for i,l in enumerate(period_lengths):
            input_flow_matrix[:l,i]=1
            
        selection = cp.Variable(shape=cost_.shape, boolean=True)
        
        # Constraints 
        assignment_constraint = cp.sum(selection,axis=1) == 1
        input_flow_= cp.sum(cp.multiply(flow_,selection),axis=1)
        input_flow_vector=cp.vec(cp.multiply(input_flow_matrix,np.ones((max(period_lengths), 1)) @ cp.reshape(input_flow_,(1,len(period_lengths)))))
        res_flow= (input_flow_vector-cp.vec(out_flow_))
        res_level=cp.cumsum(res_flow) * FACTOR + initial_level
        volume_= cp.sum(cp.multiply(volume_,selection))
        volume_constraint = volume_ >= v_min
        min_level_constraint = res_level >= min_level
        max_level_constraint = res_level <= max_level


        constraints = [assignment_constraint, max_level_constraint, min_level_constraint, volume_constraint]

        cost_ = cp.sum(cp.multiply(cost_,selection))
        assign_prob = cp.Problem(cp.Minimize(cost_),constraints)
        assign_prob.solve(solver=cp.CPLEX, verbose=True)  
        return selection, res_level
```

I have set `verbose=True` to diagnose this problem however, I am unable to find anything of use to why the problem is infeasible when it works for double the variables no problem.

The print out of this verbose is

```
===============================================================================
                                     CVXPY
                                    v1.1.12
===============================================================================
(CVXPY) Oct 20 09:26:19 AM: Your problem has 96 variables, 4 constraints, and 0 parameters.
(CVXPY) Oct 20 09:26:19 AM: It is compliant with the following grammars: DCP, DQCP
(CVXPY) Oct 20 09:26:19 AM: (If you need to solve this problem multiple times, but with different data, consider using parameters.)
(CVXPY) Oct 20 09:26:19 AM: CVXPY will first compile your problem; then, it will invoke a numerical solver to obtain a solution.
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
                                  Compilation
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
(CVXPY) Oct 20 09:26:19 AM: Compiling problem (target solver=CPLEX).
(CVXPY) Oct 20 09:26:19 AM: Reduction chain: CvxAttr2Constr -> Qp2SymbolicQp -> QpMatrixStuffing -> CPLEX
(CVXPY) Oct 20 09:26:19 AM: Applying reduction CvxAttr2Constr
(CVXPY) Oct 20 09:26:19 AM: Applying reduction Qp2SymbolicQp
(CVXPY) Oct 20 09:26:19 AM: Applying reduction QpMatrixStuffing
(CVXPY) Oct 20 09:26:19 AM: Applying reduction CPLEX
(CVXPY) Oct 20 09:26:19 AM: Finished problem compilation (took 1.000e-02 seconds).
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
                                Numerical solver
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
(CVXPY) Oct 20 09:26:19 AM: Invoking solver CPLEX  to obtain a solution.
Version identifier: 20.1.0.0 | 2020-11-11 | 9bedb6d68
CPXPARAM_Read_DataCheck                          1
Warning:  Non-integral bounds for integer variables rounded.
Tried aggregator 5 times.
MIP Presolve eliminated 96 rows and 39 columns.
MIP Presolve modified 12 coefficients.
Aggregator did 137 substitutions.
Reduced MIP has 8 rows, 16 columns, and 43 nonzeros.
Reduced MIP has 3 binaries, 8 generals, 0 SOSs, and 0 indicators.
Presolve time = 0.00 sec. (0.71 ticks)
Probing time = 0.00 sec. (0.00 ticks)
Tried aggregator 1 time.
Detecting symmetries...
Reduced MIP has 8 rows, 16 columns, and 43 nonzeros.
Reduced MIP has 3 binaries, 8 generals, 0 SOSs, and 0 indicators.
Presolve time = 0.00 sec. (0.02 ticks)
Probing time = 0.00 sec. (0.00 ticks)
MIP emphasis: balance optimality and feasibility.
MIP search method: dynamic search.
Parallel mode: deterministic, using up to 8 threads.
Root relaxation solution time = 0.00 sec. (0.01 ticks)

        Nodes                                         Cuts/
   Node  Left     Objective  IInf  Best Integer    Best Bound    ItCnt     Gap

      0     0    infeasible                                          5

Root node processing (before b&c):
  Real time             =    0.00 sec. (0.88 ticks)
Parallel b&c, 8 threads:
  Real time             =    0.00 sec. (0.00 ticks)
  Sync time (average)   =    0.00 sec.
  Wait time (average)   =    0.00 sec.
                          ------------
Total (root+branch&cut) =    0.00 sec. (0.88 ticks)
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
                                    Summary
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
(CVXPY) Oct 20 09:26:19 AM: Problem status: infeasible
(CVXPY) Oct 20 09:26:19 AM: Optimal value: inf
(CVXPY) Oct 20 09:26:19 AM: Compilation took 1.000e-02 seconds
(CVXPY) Oct 20 09:26:19 AM: Solver (including time spent in interface) took 1.400e-02 seconds
```

It seems like it is not searching through the possibilities to give us a best fitted solution, would anything have good knowledge into why CPLEX would perform this way or is this something programmatical?

Comment: Are you certain the conditions can still be met with half the periods? If not you'd neet to adjust either the inputs : cost_, volume_ and flows or the constraints v_min and levels. For example 48 periods with the same volume_ as 96 might simply not be enough to reach the minimum required volume.

Comment: Btw this is operational research and stackexchange has a dedicated site for it : https://or.stackexchange.com/ . You'll find experts in the field and others answers on mixes integer programs and cplex.

Comment: @kubatucka I believe it should still be acceptable to meet my conditions. For example, on the 96 periods, each period would be represented as [0., 8,640.] which is in litres and gives valid solutions. However the 48 periods cannot provide a solution with volume array like [0. 17280.], so it is just double it to allow the pump to run longer. I fail to see why it struggles so find an optimal solution.

Comment: Without the data you're using it's hard to say. The resulting levels might be the problem.

Comment: What other options have you tried? How about allowing a slower pump speed? What about e.g. 72 intervals? What does your feasible solution look like? Are there some or many times when the pump runs for a single time period?

Comment: I have tried, ```12, 24, 36, 48, 60, 72```. The biggest issue with the 96 intervals is the amount of starts and stops. Although it works with 15 minute intervals and seems to be the only option with a feasible solution sadly. The reservoir is reasonably small compared to other ones I have worked with in the past but typically works off level control which can take anywhere from between ```1hrs - 2hrs 30mins``` to fill back up to a desired point. I am just surprised that fewer intervals would cause an infeasible solution.